# AWS EC2 Railo image & installation procedure

Tags: amazon-ec2, railo

I got AWS EC2 free tier account & setup necessary tools to access AWS using command line & Eclipse. Is it any pre-configured Railo 3.2 image available for AWS EC2? Any configuration guidelines for the same. Is it have any restrictions like Google cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EC2 AMI: ami-bee81bd7 - http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/Railo_Installation#Cloud_Deployments

Comment: Thanks a lot @webRat, I setup the instance, it is now up & running.

Comment: Do you know default password for newly installed Railo instance's mango blog admin & mysql?

Comment: It should have asked you during installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bootstrap script. When you are launching an AMI, you have the option to provide "User-data". In that section, paste a script that installs and configures Railo for you: like the one at this github repo: https://github.com/amaroom/railo-ec2

So, you just start launching a new amazon linux instance, in the advanced section under user data paste these two lines below, and your instance will boot up with Railo server installed and ready for your code. It also installs git, so you can add a line that pulls your code from a repo as well.

```
#include
https://raw.github.com/amaroom/railo-ec2/master/boot_to_railo.sh
```